# how to turn a python file to exe file with cv2 imported

Tags: python, exe, execute

hi i have a problem where my code is turned into a executable file a error message will appear on the screen does any one know how to fix this error this is for some body tracking software  the really cause of this is cv2 but i need some help to make this a executable file so no error messages appeare when opened Many Thanks Jacob PLEASE HELO

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKJ5r.png**

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import numpy





root = Tk()
#create lebel widget
ScreenLabel = Label(root, text="Body tracking")
#put on screen
root.geometry("500x450+700+200")

#def open():
    #global track
    #track = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/dowloads", title="select A File", filetypes=([("all files","*.*")]))
e = Entry(root, width=100)
e.pack()  

def tracking():
    mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
    mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose

    video_file_path = e.get()
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)

    coordinates_list = []

    frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
    frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
    size = (frame_width, frame_height)
    fps = 30

    v_split = video_file_path.split(".")
    v_split[-2] = v_split[-2] + "_processed"
    prep_vid_file_path = ".".join(v_split)

    video_saver = cv2.VideoWriter(prep_vid_file_path, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), fps, size)

    keypoints_list = ['CENTER_HEAD',
    'LEFT_SHOULDER',
    'RIGHT_SHOULDER',
    'LEFT_ELBOW',
    'RIGHT_ELBOW',
    'LEFT_WRIST',
    'RIGHT_WRIST',
    'LEFT_PINKY',
    'RIGHT_PINKY',
    'LEFT_INDEX',
    'RIGHT_INDEX',
    'LEFT_THUMB',
    'RIGHT_THUMB',
    'LEFT_HIP',
    'RIGHT_HIP',
    'LEFT_KNEE',
    'RIGHT_KNEE',
    'LEFT_ANKLE',
    'RIGHT_ANKLE',
    'LEFT_HEEL',
    'RIGHT_HEEL',
    'LEFT_FOOT_INDEX',
    'RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX']

    with mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5) as pose:

        while True:

            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == False:
                cap.release()
                video_saver.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break

            image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image.flags.writeable = False

            results = pose.process(image)

            image.flags.writeable = True
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

            timestamp_name = str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))

            try:
                landmarks = results.pose_landmarks.landmark
                CENTER_HEAD = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.NOSE.value].z)
                LEFT_SHOULDER = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_SHOULDER.value].z)
                RIGHT_SHOULDER = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_SHOULDER.value].z)
                LEFT_ELBOW = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ELBOW.value].z)
                RIGHT_ELBOW = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ELBOW.value].z)
                LEFT_WRIST = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_WRIST.value].z)
                RIGHT_WRIST = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_WRIST.value].z)
                LEFT_PINKY = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_PINKY.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_PINKY.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_PINKY.value].z)
                RIGHT_PINKY = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_PINKY.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_PINKY.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_PINKY.value].z)
                LEFT_INDEX = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_INDEX.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_INDEX.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_INDEX.value].z)
                RIGHT_INDEX = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_INDEX.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_INDEX.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_INDEX.value].z)
                LEFT_THUMB = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_THUMB.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_THUMB.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_THUMB.value].z)
                RIGHT_THUMB = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_THUMB.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_THUMB.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_THUMB.value].z)
                LEFT_HIP = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HIP.value].z)
                RIGHT_HIP = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HIP.value].z)
                LEFT_KNEE = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_KNEE.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_KNEE.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_KNEE.value].z)
                RIGHT_KNEE = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_KNEE.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_KNEE.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_KNEE.value].z)
                LEFT_ANKLE = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ANKLE.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ANKLE.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_ANKLE.value].z)
                RIGHT_ANKLE = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ANKLE.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ANKLE.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_ANKLE.value].z)
                LEFT_HEEL = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HEEL.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HEEL.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_HEEL.value].z)
                RIGHT_HEEL = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HEEL.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HEEL.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_HEEL.value].z)
                LEFT_FOOT_INDEX = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_FOOT_INDEX.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_FOOT_INDEX.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.LEFT_FOOT_INDEX.value].z)
                RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX = (landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX.value].x, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX.value].y, landmarks[mp_pose.PoseLandmark.RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX.value].z)
                coordinates_list.append(str(timestamp_name) + " : " + str({'CENTER_HEAD':CENTER_HEAD,
                                                                            'LEFT_SHOULDER':LEFT_SHOULDER,
                                                                            'RIGHT_SHOULDER':RIGHT_SHOULDER,
                                                                            'LEFT_ELBOW':LEFT_ELBOW,
                                                                            'RIGHT_ELBOW':RIGHT_ELBOW,
                                                                            'LEFT_WRIST':LEFT_WRIST,
                                                                            'RIGHT_WRIST':RIGHT_WRIST,
                                                                            'LEFT_PINKY':LEFT_PINKY,
                                                                            'RIGHT_PINKY':RIGHT_PINKY,
                                                                            'LEFT_INDEX':LEFT_INDEX,
                                                                            'RIGHT_INDEX':RIGHT_INDEX,
                                                                            'LEFT_THUMB':LEFT_THUMB,
                                                                            'RIGHT_THUMB':RIGHT_THUMB,
                                                                            'LEFT_HIP':LEFT_HIP,
                                                                            'RIGHT_HIP':RIGHT_HIP,
                                                                            'LEFT_KNEE':LEFT_KNEE,
                                                                            'RIGHT_KNEE':RIGHT_KNEE,
                                                                            'LEFT_ANKLE':LEFT_ANKLE,
                                                                            'RIGHT_ANKLE':RIGHT_ANKLE,
                                                                            'LEFT_HEEL':LEFT_HEEL,
                                                                            'RIGHT_HEEL':RIGHT_HEEL,
                                                                            'LEFT_FOOT_INDEX':LEFT_FOOT_INDEX,
                                                                            'RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX':RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX}))
            
            
            except:
                pass


            mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(image, results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

            video_saver.write(image)
            cv2.imshow("Video Feed", image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
            
    v_split = video_file_path.split(".")
    v_split[-1] = "txt"
    v_split[-2] = v_split[-2] + "_coordinates"
    coordinates_file_path = ".".join(v_split)

    with open(coordinates_file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write("\n".join(coordinates_list))

    v_split = video_file_path.split(".")
    v_split[-1] = "xlsx"
    v_split[-2] = v_split[-2] + "_excel"
    coordinates_excel_path = ".".join(v_split)

    def get_vals(x):
        vals = []
        for i in x:
            for j in i:
                vals.append(j)
        return vals

    df = pd.DataFrame(coordinates_list)
    df["frame"] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split(" : ")[0])
    df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: get_vals(literal_eval(x.split(" : ")[1]).values()))
    df_columns = []
    mapper_dict = {0:"x", 1:"y", 2:"z"}
    for keypoint in keypoints_list:
        for i in range(0,3):
            df_columns.append(keypoint+"_"+mapper_dict.get(i))
    df = pd.concat([df["frame"], pd.DataFrame(df[0].to_list(), columns=df_columns)], axis=1)
    df.to_excel(coordinates_excel_path, index=False)

#open_btn = Button( root, text="open File", command=open, borderwidth=0).pack()





ExportButton = Button(root,  text="Track", command=tracking ,borderwidth=0 ,fg="blue")
ExportButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73081291/9705687). Seems there is an issue with PyInstaller and OpenCV. Might be fixed in PyInstaller version 5.3.